# Dimension of Row Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given matrix

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Question: I know I can write $\operatorname{row}(A) = \operatorname{span}{(1,2),(2,4)} = \operatorname{span}{(1,2)}$. So is the dimension of $\operatorname{row}(A)=1$.

So my confusion is that to calculate the dimension of the row or column space, do I have to check if the vectors in the span are linearly independent first ? And just to confirm, the dimension of the row and column space are always equal right?

So is this correct:

$$A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3 & -5 & 1 & -3 \\ 1 & 2 & -2 & 2 & -1
\end{bmatrix}$$

a) Calculate dimension of $\operatorname{row}(A)$, $\operatorname{col}(A)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A)$.

$$\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{row}(A))=\operatorname{dim}(\operatorname{col}(A))=\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$$

b) Find a basis of $\operatorname{row}(A)$

I reduced to echelon form: $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-5}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

- Basis = $\left\{\left(1,-1,3,1,2\right),\left(0,1,\frac{-5}{3},\frac{1}{3},-1\right)\right\}$

c) Find a basis of $\operatorname{col}(A)$

- Basis = $\left\{\left(1,2,0,1\right),\left(-1,1,3,2\right)\right\}$

Final question: Am I correct in saying that

$$\operatorname{row}(A) =\operatorname{span}\left\{\left(1,-1,3,1,2\right),\left(2,1,1,3,1\right),\left(0,3,-5,1,-3\right),\left(1,2,-2,2,-1\right)\right\}=\\=\operatorname{span}\left\{\left(1,-1,3,1,2\right),\left(0,1,\frac{-5}{3},\frac{1}{3},-1\right)\right\}$$

Comment: You find the maximal independent set and choose this set as your span.

Comment: @MathFail Okay I understand. If I edit my question to a different example, could you tell me if my answer is correct ?

Comment: what example? you can do the standard procedure to find the maximal independent set, just watch out computation errors when you do the row/column reduction.

Comment: There is a typo here: row(A) = span{$(1,2),(3,4)$}.

Comment: The general way to proceed is by elimination 

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 2 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \to \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @user Thanks I edited. Can you check my new question in my post so I can understand correctly please?

Comment: @MathFail I put a new example which I solved using your advice and wanted to know if it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your way to proceed is fine, more in detail:

- by the row reduced echelon form we can easily find the rank of the matrix, which is alway equal to dimension of row space and column space,
- a basis for the column space is given by the original columns which contains the pivots,
- for the row space the elimination process by row operations
  preserves the row space therefore both span you have determined are
  fine, but only the second one is a basis.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.